# Azure: Could not load file or assembly MySql.Data

Tags: mysql, azure

I'm trying to call a MySQL database located on another server, from Azure.
I'm referencing .Net MySql.Data, and it works when running it in a test application.
However when I deploy the code to the Azure server I get the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Since it's part of .Net I would expect it to work on Azure so I suspect I may be doing something wrong.
I also tried adding the MySql.Data.dll to the project and installing it to the CAG with no luck. (However I'm not certain it was installed successfully)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you set its "Copy Local" attribute to TRUE after you added it as Reference? Adding to your GAC will not help in any way, but "Copy Local" to "TRUE" will help!

Comment: I tried setting Copy Local to true, but it didn't help. I'm just referencing the one in the .Net framework. Would it help any to add he DLL to the project and reference that instead?

Comment: are you sure you repackaged the deployment? I shall work without the need of a startup task and ugly GAC-ing ...

Comment: I did the issue was that I was referencing MySql.Data from a project which I then referenced from the service I was publishing. I thought the service would take all the content of the bin folder on build, but I was wrong. Added MySql.Data to the service and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you assuming MySql.Data is part of .NET? The [connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) was written in .NET, it's not part of .NET. You will need to make sure the assembly is available in your instances. Since copy local didn't work (it should work...), try the following:

1. Add both **gacutil.exe** and **MySql.Data.dll** in a folder (mysql for example) in your project and set Copy to Output Directory to always.
2. Then create a startup task that calls gacutil.exe and installs the assembly, something like: `mysql\gacutil.exe /i mysql\MySql.Data.dll`

Note: I'm assuming you're using a Web Role.

Comment: I did actually try using a startup task to install it. But not sure if it was actually successful (Didn't seem to help). However I now realized that I had included the binary in the project where it was used, however this was a library used by a service, so the binary got copied to the bin folder of the library but not to the actual service which was getting deployed. It worked after I added it to the service as well. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Just going to accept this answer. In the end the problem was that the binary wasn't getting published to the server. Just had to make sure it was also included in the service I was deploying. (I guess I thought everything would get copied from the bin folder in the project I was referencing, it didn't)